# What tools are available for collaborating with a small number of people?

Tags: collaboration

I am collaborating with someone on a project and currently use Skype for collaboration. I like it because we can be on a call to say things that are hard to say by typing out.  We can share our screens so we can help with code writing. And we can use the text chat to copy-paste code between each other. We also use Subversion for version control.

I just wanted to know what other people used for collaborating with others so I could see whats out there to use.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

By the way, Google docs help a lot too here! And come at a great price - free!
Their tools, comparable to Word, Excel are all free and read for collaboration.

Answer (score 1):

You also need an issue tracker. I prefer [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) which brings on a bunch of other project management features as well.

Comment: Are there any other issue tracking programs that are easier to use?

Answer (score 0):

We're are leveraging email for project related collaboration with this tool:

http://yoxel.com/personal-commitment-manager.html

We also use Skype alot.

Answer (score -1):

For service oriented businesses, such as programming, you may benefit in collaboration from a well rounded application that lets you manage multiple aspects of your work.

I'm not sure what you use besides Skype right now, but I'm assuming somehow you're taking care of other aspects of your business too, most likely through email or some small scale CRM. If you want to help speed up your workflow and save some time, WORKetc could be worth checking into. It combines CRM with PM and Billing, but brings collaboration to all of these as well. Basically, under one app you manage all clients, their projects, and can bill them either through your own system or by integrating merchants like Paypal. Because in WORKetc you manage everything centrally, you don't need to jump between a list of apps to find specific information, and this can be especially useful when collaborating with others (which you can do for free btw).